# Unable to get Dynamic output using Methods

Tags: ruby

I am very new to ruby,And I had written the method with arguments passing dynamic values,But I don't get the expected result while passing values dynamically.Can any one help me the issue in below code

```
def addition (digit1,digit2)
  puts "Sum of the two digits are #{digit1+digit2}"
end

print "Enter the First Value"
d1 = gets

print "Enter the Second Value"
d2 = gets

addition(d1,d2)
gets
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Why do you define as "dynamic values"?

Comment: can you specify what is the expected result and what is the one you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gets` returns a String. You, therefore, pass two strings to the `addition` method and the `+` in there does its job on the two strings: it concatenates them.

In order to pass numbers to that function, you could call `.to_i` on the result of `gets` to convert it to a number.

So, here's the adjusted code:

```
def addition (digit1, digit2)
  puts "Sum of the two digits are #{digit1 + digit2}"
end

puts "Enter the First Value"
d1 = gets.to_i

puts "Enter the Second Value"
d2 = gets.to_i

addition(d1,d2)
gets
```

And here's how it works: http://ideone.com/nyXJbH

*Note that I also converted the `print`statements to `puts` to slightly enhance output readability.*